# List comprehension won't return expected output

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm trying to solve the [Google's Python Basic Exercises](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/basic) and I tried solving this particular one about lists with list comprehension:

```
# D. Given a list of numbers, return a list where
# all adjacent == elements have been reduced to a single element,
# so [1, 2, 2, 3] returns [1, 2, 3]. You may create a new list or
# modify the passed in list.
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  newList = []
  newList = [i for i in nums if len(newList) == 0 or nums[i] != newList[-1]]
  return newList
```

Obviously, output is not what I expected, and the author-made test function underlines this:

```
got: [2, 2, 3, 3, 3] expected [2, 3]
got: [1, 2, 2, 3] expected [1, 2, 3]
```

What's wrong with my function?

Comment: Your `i` is used as both an item in the list `nums` and as an index into it...

Comment: cant you just simply use set???

Comment: @Hackaholic, the OP is removing adjacent elements not getting removing all dups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `newList` you are referring to inside the list comprehension expression always stays the same empty list `[]` as you assigned it initially. The expression `[i for i in nums if len(newList) == 0 or nums[i] != newList[-1]]` is calculated first using the existing variable, and only then the result is assigned to `newList`.

In other words, your code is equivalent to

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  newList = []
  otherList = [i for i in nums if len(newList) == 0 or nums[i] != newList[-1]]
  return otherList
```

You don't have to use list comprehension to solve this problem (and personally I wouldn't because it gets tricky in this case).

Comment: I know I can also not use list comprehension, in fact the author itself uses `result = []
  for num in nums:
    if len(result) == 0 or num != result[-1]:
      result.append(num)
  return result`

Comment: @GioacchinoGargiulo, that's correct, but that's another question. Does my post answers your initial question about what was wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
def adj(l):
   if len(l) in {0,1}: # check for empty or list with 1 element
       return l
   return [ele for ind, ele in enumerate(l[:-1]) if ele != l[ind+1]] + [l[-1]]
```

`if ele != l[ind+1]]`checks the current element against the  element at the next index in the list, we go to `l[:-1]` so `l[ind+1]` does not give an index error, because of this we need to add `l[-1]` the last element to the result.

```
In [44]: l = [1, 2, 2, 3]

In [45]: adj(l)
Out[45]: [1, 2, 3]

In [46]: l = [1, 2, 2, 3,2]

In [47]: adj(l)
Out[47]: [1, 2, 3, 2]

In [48]: l = [2,2,2,2,2]

In [49]: adj(l)
Out[49]: [2]
```

Using your own code you would need a for loop as `newList` is assigned  to the list comprehension, you are not updating your original assignment of `newList` you have reassigned the name to the list comprehension which is a completely new object:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    if len(l) in {0,1}: # catch empty and single element list
        return l
    newList = [nums[0]] # add first element to avoid index error with `newList[-1]`
    for i in nums[1:]: # start at second element and iterate over the element
        if i != newList[-1]:
            newList.append(i)
    return newList


In [1]: l = [] # assign l to empty list

In [2]: id(l)
Out[2]: 140592635860536 # object id

In [3]: l = [x for x in range(2)] # reassign 

In [4]: id(l)
Out[4]: 140592635862264 # new id new object
```

Comment: This does not answer the question: _What's wrong with my function?_

Comment: Well that may solve the request from the author of the exercise, but still I don't get why my code is wrong.

Comment: @GioacchinoGargiulo: That's why I posted another answer.

Comment: @GioacchinoGargiulo, you are creating a list comprehension which is a new object  not modifying the  list  you assign to first with `newList = []`

Comment: no worries, you can use a list comprehension n0 problem, you are indexing `nums[-1]` each iteration in the for loop so `l[ind+1]` is doing the same